# Python Selenium - Multiple choice field (django-select2) - Cannot get a value by XPATH

Tags: python, django, forms, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get a random value from multiple choice field (categories) to make a test in Python Selenium:

```
tag = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='s2id_autogen2']")
```

That works if I want to send just a string, for example:

```
tag.send_keys("some_text")
```

But I'd like to get those values that are in options (page source code):

```
<div class="form-select-container" >
      <select multiple="multiple" class="django-select2" data-allow-clear="false" data-minimum-input-length="0" id="id_categories" name="categories">
      <option value="1">String1</option>
      <option value="2">String2</option>
      <option value="3">String3</option>
</select>
</div>
```

And select a random value.

With my code it doesn't work, it doesn't even print the number of elements:

```
for i in tag:
    print len(i)
    #print (random.choice(i))(Keys.ENTER)
```

And this the code from Chrome Console:
[image: Chrome Code]

Answer (score 0):

Locate the select element by `id`, instantiate the [`Select` object](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select), get the [`.options`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select.options) and pick the one randomly using `random.choice()`:

```
import random

from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

# get a random option
select_elm = driver.find_element_by_id("id_categories")
select = Select(select_elm)
random_option = random.choice(select.options)

# select the random option
select_elm.click()
random_option.click()
```

Comment: I get: AttributeError: Select instance has no attribute 'click'

Comment: Hmm... Next problem is: Message: element not visible

Comment: I changed my ID to "s2id_autogen1" and I got:

UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on <input>